# print is blocking BufferedReader input?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I am trying to parallel execute my code, but got now a problem.
The code without parallel execution is waiting for input (1) and then he is printing out something (2).
Now I execute my code parallel with the help of a timer (task2) and for the input (1)I got another loop.

Now if I try to write something down but I am not fast enough, the input isn't reading the whole input which was interrupted by the task2 with the print out.

```
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
static PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);

static void test1(BufferedReader in, PrintStream out) throws IOException {
    String input = in.readLine();
    if (input.equals("test"))
        System.out.println("true input");
    else System.out.println("false input");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("print"); 
                Thread.sleep(1000);}}}, 1000);
    while (true)
        test1(in, out);

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc3fL.jpg

Comment: Like I did understand, it starts after 1000ms and then goes in the loop with the 1000ms wait, without the loop inside it would go in, print -> wait 1000ms and go out

Comment: Are you saying `in.readLine()` returns incomplete lines? Partial input even when you did not press Enter?

Comment: if I want to write the input "test" but I could only write "te" and then the print comes with "print" the "te" isn't even counted and only if I write the last "st" with enter, the "st" is counted as input

Comment: That seems unlikely. It probably looks weird when you print your output all over your input prompt, but it should not mess up what you are reading from that input.

Comment: I added a picture where the input was: "test"+enter without interruption, then "te" waiting for the print and "st" + enter and the last just writing something until the print will block all and just press enter https://imgur.com/iyIdWeA

Answer (score 0):

You could read single characters until you press Enter.

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
char ch;
while((ch = in.read()) != '\n'){
    strBuilder.append(ch);
}
String input = strBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Thats not working it also works like with in.readLine(). If I write something down then it still doesn't count the input before the print. (exactly the same as at the picture)